# Dexter New Blood : Was this scene real?

Tags: dexter, dexter-new-blood

Spoilers for 2021 Showtime series Dexter:New Blood.

In episode 05 (Runaway), Harrison consumes an Ecstasy pill in a party and is shown to get intoxicated and a blurred vision. One of the girls in the party asks Harrison to carve his initials into her foot, but once Harrison starts carving she starts to panic and her friend seems to be suddenly alerted and tends to the girl quickly. Meanwhile Harrison dozes off from the scene.

Since Harrison experiences this while he's on drugs, it's hard to figure out if it really happened or not. For example, asking someone to carve their initials on their body using a kitchen knife seems over the top, and the way the atmosphere suddenly changes once Harrison carves the first line on her leg and the girl panicking makes it look like a hallucination that Harrison experiences, since he has a connection to blood like his father. Also it seems weird since none of the students in the party mentions this incident later in the episode.

Comment: Currently (as of episode 7), we have no reason to believe it's not real.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are asking if the girl really asked him to carve into her leg or if he hallucinated that part?

With the information we have there are basically two possibilities of it not being real.

1. She didn't ask him to do it and he hallucinated it
2. None of it happened at all, including the cutting

It's unlikely that Harrison would not have had any consequences to cutting a girl that didn't ask for him to cut her, so I think we can easily rule out the first one. So either the whole thing was hallucinated including the aftermath, or it was all real.